# extract sequences from fasta file

Tags: python, file, sequences, fasta

how to extract sequences from fasta file
if I have for example a fasta file which contains 9 sequences, each time I take 3 sequences from the file then I calculate the distance between the three sequences :

```
distance(seq1,seq2,seq3)
```

then I take the other three sequences

```
sequences=[]
with open('example.fasta', 'r') as file:
    for Seq_record in SeqIO.parse(file, 'fasta'):
        format_string = "%s" % Seq_record.seq
        sequence.append (format string)
```

from the 3 sequences in the file how can I assign the first sequence to seq1 and the second sequence to seq2 and the third sequence to seq3

```
from example.fasta:
seq1=the first sequence
seq2=second sequence
seq3=the third sequence
```

then I calculate `distance(seq1,seq2,seq3)`
then, do the same thing for the rest of sequences in the file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you append each sequence to a list called `sequences`. You can access each individual sequence in the list simply using a number in square brackets:

```
sequences=[]
with open('example.fasta', 'r') as file:
    for Seq_record in SeqIO.parse(file, 'fasta'):
        format_string = "%s" % Seq_record.seq
        sequences.append(format_string)

seq1 = sequences[0]
seq2 = sequences[1]
seq3 = sequences[2]
distance(seq1, seq2, seq3)
```

Alternatively, you could skip creating seq1, seq2, seq3 and just pass the list elements straight to distance:

```
distance(sequences[0], sequences[1], sequences[2])
```

If you want to generally look at all the sequences in the file in groups of three:

```
for x in range(0, len(sequences), 3):
    distance(sequences[x], sequences[x+1], sequences[x+2])
```

Comment: OK. thank you.for the fourth and fiftieth and the sixth sequences (the rest of sequences in the file). how to do?

Comment: I edited the answer for the general case of any length file. Otherwise just use `sequences[3]`, `sequences[4]` and `sequences[5]` for the fourth, fifth and sixth sequences.